# Create tar gz on linux with specific list of files from sed output

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, tar

Here is my command line:

```
find . -type f -exec file {} \; \
| sed 's/\(.*png\): .* \([0-9]* x [0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' \
| sed 's/\(.*jpg\): .* \([0-9]*x[0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' \
| awk 'int($1) < 1000' \
| sed 's/^.*[[:blank:]]//' \
| tar -czvf images.tar.gz --null -T -
```

And the error i got is:

> tar: Unix\n./test.png\n./test2.jpg\n: Cannot stat: No such file or
>   directory
>   tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

What i want is to find all images in current directory, who's width less than 1000 px and tar them into archive.

Comment: Why did you add `--null` to the `tar` command?

Comment: The error message is including `\n` which almost always is the "new-line" character. Weird that it is in there, nothing in your code seems to be creating it. Are you sure the error message matches the code? Also, you can probably get by with `find ... | awk ... | tar ...`  You can do multiple substitutions in one instance of `awk` and print/test $2 instead of $1. (and other non-optimal stuff for a later time). Presumably, you built this cmd up 1 addition at a time? If not, go back a add 1 more pipe and study the changes made from the previous. AND why not `find  -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*png'`?

Comment: @shellter: because of `--null`, `tar` expects filenames to be `\0`-separated.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : Are you replying to melpomene ?

Comment: @shellter: no, to you `:)`. Good luck `;)`.

Comment: @shellter: that's why you see all these `\n`'s: `tar` slurped the whole stream and considers it as a unique filename.

Comment: Agree, I didn't want to go there in my response ;-) So the Q is why is the pipeline creating a giant string? I don't see it in the code provided. Good luck and Happy New Year to you! ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, my mistake with that `--null` option.

Comment: @shellter i tried like: `find . -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' -exec file {} \;` and `find . -type f -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg" -exec file {} \;`. in case with `-exec file {} \;`, it just gave me not full list of filenames by some reason. Then i thought just to try with `-type f` option and later redirect error stream to null when tar will create archive, but this is bad logic. Better to use somehow as you mentioned `-iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to use `--null`, you need to convert newlines to nulls first:

```
...
| tr '\n' '\0' \
| tar -czvf images.tar.gz --null -T -
```

(tested, working.)

also, here are a number of suggestions on speed and style in decreasing order of importance.

a. don't find and run `file` on more files than you need to:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg"
```

b. for commands that can run on multiple files per command, such as `file`, use `xargs` to save a lot of time:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

c. if you put `|` at the end of each line, you can continue on the next line without also using `\`.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg" -print0 |
  xargs -0 file
```

d. you can save yourself a lot of trouble since your max width is 999 by just `grep`ing for 1, 2, or 3 digit widths, though the `awk '$1<1000'` is ultimately better in case you ever want to use a different threshold:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg" -print0 |
  xargs -0 file |
  grep ', [0-9][0-9]\?[0-9]\? x '
```

e. `grep` and `awk` are faster than `sed`, so use them where possible:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg" -print0 |
  xargs -0 file |
  grep ', [0-9][0-9]\?[0-9]\? x ' |
  grep -o -i '.*\.\(png\|jpg\)'
```

final command:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpg" -print0 |
  xargs -0 file |
  grep ', [0-9][0-9]\?[0-9]\? x ' |
  grep -o -i '.*\.\(png\|jpg\)' |
  tr '\n' '\0' |
  tar -czvf images.tar.gz --null -T -
```

Comment: This work for *size min 1000px*. How do you same research, but where limit become *`2000px`*  or  *`2520px`* ?

Comment: F. Hauri's and Bertrand Martel's answers both support arbitrary width_limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `awk` only with :

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.png" -or -name "*.jpg" \)  -exec file {} \; | awk -v width_limit=1000 '
    {
        match($0, /,\s+([0-9]+)\s*x\s*([0-9]+)/, items)

        if (items[1] < width_limit){
            match($0, /(.*):/, filename)
            print filename[1]
        }             
    }' | tar -czvf allfiles.tar -T -
```

The width can be configured with `width_limit` variable

Answer (score 1):

## Quick way using `perl`:

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + |
    perl -ne '
        print $1."\0" if /^(.*):\s*(JPEG|PNG).*,\s*(\d+)\s+x\s*\d+\s*,/ &&
             $3 < 1000;
        ' | tar -czvf images.tar.gz --null -T -
```

Using `+` operator to `find` as same effect than `print0 | xargs -0`.

Comment: "using + operator to find as same effect than print0 | xargs -0" . . . i always forget about that. thanks for the reminder :)